# Intuition: Null Space being Subspace of Domain

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $V,W$ are finite-dimensional vector spaces.

Consider the set of all linear maps from $V$ to $W$, denoted $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$.

Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ and denote the null space of $T$ as null($T$).

Claim: The null space of each linear map is a subspace of the domain.

I understood and worked out the proof, but what is the intuition that the null space is a subspace of the domain? A silly question is why can it not be the subspace of the range? Is there any intuition if you were to explain to an introductory linear algebra student?

Reference:
Axler, Sheldon J. $\textit{Linear Algebra Done Right}$, New York: Springer, 2015.

Comment: I would say it's rather definition than intuition: the nullspace of $T$ is the set of elements that are mapped to zero. And $T$ is mapping only elements from its domain.

Comment: @Berci Great. Can you formalize/elaborate your answer? I will choose your response.

Comment: I think you could have answered this question for yourself if you had simple spelled out the definition of a nullspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The null space is the space of vectors (of the domain) that are mapped by the operator $T$ into the zero vector (of the codomain) . So, by definition, the null space has to be a subset of the domain of $T$, because it contains vectors that *are transformed by* the operator, **not** the vectors that the operator *transformes into*.